# Colocar ventanas en pantalla con QT

Tags: c++, windows, qt

Estoy realizando una aplicación en C++ mediante QT Creator que abre varias ventanas a la vez. El problema viene en que todas se colocan centradas unas encima de otras, ¿cuál es la operación que permite situar las ventanas en una parte concreta de la pantalla?.
Saludos.

Comment: Para entender mejor tu pregunta editala y muestra el código

Comment: ¿Cómo estás creando las ventanas?

Comment: Podrías incluir el código de tu aplicación y/o una foto donde se muestre tu problema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con el método **void setGeometry(int x, int y, int width, int height)**  puedes definir la posición de la esquina superior izquierda y su ancho y alto.

Un ejemplo:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QWidget>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QWidget w1,w2,w3,w4;
    w1.setGeometry(50,0,200,200);
    w2.setGeometry(300,0,200,200);
    w3.setGeometry(50,300,200,200);
    w4.setGeometry(300,300,200,200);
    w1.show();
    w2.show();
    w3.show();
    w4.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Esto te muestra cuatro ventanas con una posición y dimensiones iniciales. Esta característica la puedes encontrar en el QDesigner, si estás diseñando la ventana allí.

Comment: Perfecto, justo lo que buscaba, gracias :).